# pandas groupby and aggregate by different factors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using python 3 and pandas.

I have a dataframe;

tpfs.info()

```
     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2121 entries, 2019-05-15 00:10:00 to 2019-05-31 23:52:00
Data columns (total 4 columns):
bg         2121 non-null int64
carbs      2121 non-null float64
humalog    2121 non-null float64
lantus     2121 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1)
memory usage: 162.9 KB
```

The data looks like this;

```
                        bg  carbs   humalog lantus
time                
2019-05-30 08:36:00 150     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 08:52:00 154     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:00:00 158     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:00:00 0       39.0    0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:00:00 0       0.0     2.5     0.0
2019-05-30 09:00:00 0       0.0     0.0     13.0
2019-05-30 09:07:00 161     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:23:00 163     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:36:00 160     0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-05-30 09:38:00 156     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

I want to aggregate the data such that I have rows for each 24 hour period that show the mean of the bg and the sums for the carbs, humalog and lantus.

I've tried various combinations of groupby and agg, and gotten various error messages back.  The bottom line is that I'm just cutting a pasting code from various sources and trying to tweak them to fit my use case without fully understanding how they work.

Notwithstanding the Q&A examples, documentation and How Tos I have poured over, I can't seem to find an example that comes close enough to what I am trying to do to apply.  Perhaps extracting 2 new dataframes (one for the bg mean and one for the sums, then combining them.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `.resample()` combined with `.agg()`:

```
tpfs.resample('24h').agg({
    'bg':'mean',
    'carbs':'sum',
    'humalog':'sum',
    'lantus':'sum'
})
```